# How to use python to share a outlook calendar

Tags: win32com, outlook-calendar

I want to share my outlook calendar with other exchange users by using the win32com.

According to the Office VBA Reference [Sharing Calendars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/sharing-calendars) I want to create a `SharingItem` by using the method `CreateSharingItem` but failed.

blow is my code:

```
ol = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
session = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
sharefolder = session.GetDefaultFolder(9)
shareitem = session.CreateSharingItem(sharefolder)
```

and the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\wah2hi\comment\test\test\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    shareitem = session.CreateSharingItem(sharefolder)
  File "C:\Users\wah2hi\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\2.7\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x5\_NameSpace.py", line 62, in CreateSharingItem
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(64484, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17)), Context, Provider)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

So, if I use the `CreateSharingItem` method in a wrong way or are there some other ways to share a calendar by using win32com?